# How to split a text file into sentences for word2vec/gensim

Tags: python, spacy, gensim

I have extracted about 40MB of the English wikipedia into plain text. I would to use it to build a word2vec model with gensim. To do this I need to split it into sentences first. How can I do this?  I tried:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.max_length = 47084146
ftest = open("test_02", "r")
raw_test = ftest.read().replace("\n", " ")
sentences = [i for i in nlp(raw_test).sents] 

f = open("sentences.txt", "w")

for sent in sentences:
    f.write(str(sent)+"\n")
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

But this fails with: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 34.8 GiB for an array with shape (9112793, 8, 64, 2) and data type float32`

I have no idea why it wants to use so much RAM!

How can I do this?

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../processwiki.py", line 8, in <module>
    sentences = [i for i in nlp(raw_test).sents] 
  File "/mnt/storage/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 449, in __call__
    doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 233, in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.__call__
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 274, in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.predict
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 287, in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.greedy_parse
  File "/mnt/storage/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 167, in __call__
    return self.predict(x)
  File "/mnt/storage/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 131, in predict
    y, _ = self.begin_update(X, drop=None)
  File "_parser_model.pyx", line 243, in spacy.syntax._parser_model.ParserModel.begin_update
  File "_parser_model.pyx", line 300, in spacy.syntax._parser_model.ParserStepModel.__init__
  File "_parser_model.pyx", line 425, in spacy.syntax._parser_model.precompute_hiddens.__init__
  File "/mnt/storage/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/_ml.py", line 183, in begin_update
    Yf = self._add_padding(Yf)
  File "/mnt/storage/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/_ml.py", line 214, in _add_padding
    Yf_padded = self.ops.xp.vstack((self.pad, Yf))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in vstack
  File "/mnt/storage/software/languages/anaconda/Anaconda3-2020.02-tflow-2.2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 283, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 34.8 GiB for an array with shape (9112793, 8, 64, 2) and data type float32
```

Comment: can you post full stack trace?

Comment: @Marat Updated with the trace.

Comment: small thing, but the line `sentences = [i for i in nlp(raw_test).sents]` is converting a generator into a list, and then later you iterate over the list: `for sent in sentences:` instead you should iterate over the generator. This uses less memory, although I don't think that is your problem.

Comment: is it safe to assume that `test_02` doesn't have newline characters in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: @AlpacaJones good point

Comment: @Marat it might. I just got it from the wikipedia by runnnig a text extraction tool. But that isn't causing it to us 35GB of RAM and crash is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the content of `test_02` is processed at once, and the intermediate data structures don't fit in memory. Processing it in chunks should solve the problem. For example, if sentences are never split between lines, gradual processing would look like:

```
with  open("test_02", "r") as ftest, open("sentences.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in ftest:
        for sent in nlp(line).sents:
            f.write(str(sent)+"\n")
```

Since sentences can stretch over multiple lines, you might want to use a different strategy of splitting `test_02`, e.g. by splitting on double newline instead `for line in ftest.read().split('\n\n')` but most likely even this naive approach will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, this does fix the crash. It is amazingly slow though when all I am doing is splitting sentences. Do you know what it is doing under the hood?

Comment: @fomin I don't know for sure, but it should be model-dependent, and, most likely, based on probablistic approach rather than pattern matching. I can understand why it is slower than splitting by regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The proximate cause of your `MemoryError` is loading a lot of things into memory that don't need to be.

First the entire `test_02` file is brought into addressable memory as a single giant string. (You must have a lot of memory, as this step would fail for many!)

The replace of all newlines with spaces – why, exactly? – likely then temporarily doubles the memory requirements, as `.replace()` returns a copy. (Still, amazingly, you haven't yet exhausted memory.)

Then, asking Spacy to parse the massive text – Spacy's parsing often being an involved step, itself – triggers the error deep in Spacy code. (But if by some luck or expansive system memory that didn't trigger an error, your very next line might, as it attempts to create an in-heap list of all the `.sents`.)

The good news is: you probably don't need to do any of this. Despite the name of the parameter to gensim `Word2Vec`, `sentences`, it doesn't actually require legal sentences. It just requires texts, where each text is a list-of-string-tokens. (These can be full articles/docs of many paragraphs, or whatever. Some uses of word2vec even leave in punctuation tokens as pseudowords.)

Your `test_02` file, if it's already been tokenized into the 'words' you want where each line is a reasonably-sized text and words are delimited by single spaces, may already be nearly ready to be passed to `Word2Vec`. Try...

```py
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence
corpus = LineSentence('test_02')
```

..then supply `corpus` as the `sentences` parameter to `Word2Vec`. If in fact your `test_02` needs more sophisticated preprocessing/tokenization, do that first, maybe using Spacy if you need that level of sophistication, then creating a file with a text per line and space-separated tokens.

At no point is it necessary to load the whole corpus into a single in-heap string or list; it can and almost always should be streamed from disk, as needed, to avoid consuming so much main memory.

Comment: This looks promising. I do want to lemmatize, remove punctuation etc the document before giving it to word2vec. If I can do that without splitting the sentences, all the better.

Comment: If you want to do those, I'd suggest doing that then writing the results to a simple space-delimited text file for `Word2Vec` to operate on. In that format, you could also use the newer `corpus_file` variant for specifying your corpus, which can achieve higher parallelism. (However, note that if any one line has more than 10K tokens, those over 10K will be silently ignored. The `LineSentence` will auto-break longer lines into separate texts, so you could use that to rewrite the corpus as shorter lines.)

Comment: But also: you may not need to do lemmatization or punctuation removal. It's not always done with word2vec, and lemmatization is usually of more value if your corpus is very thin. (Then, at least, combining variant words gives you ore shared examples of their use.) If you instead have plentiful examples of word-variants, each variant will get an adequate vector, and the variants will wind up near each other in useful ways, and you'll be able to look them up as themselves, not the lemmatized-mangled versions.

Comment: What is the format of `corpus_file`? Googling doesn't seem to tell me.

Comment: One text per line ended with newline, tokens separated by spaces - the same format as is expected by the utility class `LineSentence` I've mentioned & described. See the docs for the `corpus_file` parameter & associated links: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec